# Java Calendar and date format

Tags: java, date

I am confused by Java `Calendar`. Why does the exception occur when I run this code:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println(dateFormat.format("todayDate : " + cal2.getTime()));
```

Here is Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Date
    at java.text.DateFormat.format(DateFormat.java:301)
    at java.text.Format.format(Format.java:157)
    at test.CleanDirectory.main(CleanDirectory.java:20)
```

Answer (score 3):

Because you are trying to format the string `todayDate : <Date>` to the Format "yyyy-MM-dd" what is not possible.

Change to

```
System.out.println("todayDate : " + dateFormat.format(cal2.getTime()));
```

Answer (score 3):

The `dateFormat.format` takes instance of `Date` class.
Probably you should write like this:
`System.out.println("todayDate : " + dateFormat.format(cal2.getTime()));`

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are correct.

## java.time

But you are using old outmoded troublesome classes. They have been supplanted by the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later.

```
String output = LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ).toString() ;
```

And you are ignoring the **crucial issue of time zone**. Determining a date requires a time zone. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by time zone.

If you omit the optional time zone argument, your JVM‘s current default time zone is applied. That default can change, even during runtime(!). So better to always specify your desired/expected time zone.

The output format you want is defined by the [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard. The java.time classes use these formats by default. So no need to define a formatting pattern.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( zoneId );
String output = today.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

`DateFormat.format` expects a `Date`, you are passing a string with `"todayDate :"` prepended.

This should work:

```
System.out.println("todayDate : " + dateFormat.format(cal2.getTime()));
```

Answer (score 1):

you have written the syntax wrongly while formatting it expecting the date object.

```
    System.out.println("todayDate : " + dateFormat.format(cal2.getTime()));
```